# add finishing separator on uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom separator style (fairly simple):

```
[[UITableView appearance] setSeparatorColor:SOMECOLOR];
```

Now I want to have my tableview finish with a separator. Currently separators only appear between two cells, but I want to have a separator at the end.

see here:

[image: no seperator appears]

any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it you want a separator at the end as well? You can add a footer view to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make my own separator inside the table view cell. I do this with a `UIView` that spans the width of the cell and is 1 or 2 points high.

In your case, if you want the system separator, you would have to add a custom cell at the end which is all transparent and 1 point high. UITableView would then add the missing separator.

Answer (score 0):

Make a footer view with height of 0.0001. To do so simply implement the following tableview delegate method :

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.001;
}`